# Setting up virtualenvwrapper to work with Python 2.7.9

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

For work reasons, i have to use `Python 2.7.9`. On my system, OS X Yosemite, i have version `2.7.11`. There is a way to set up an enviroment via virtualenvwrapper in order to use that specific version of Python?

Comment: You should have a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv#11301911

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `-p` option:

```
$ virtualenv --help
Usage: virtualenv [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose         Increase verbosity.
  -q, --quiet           Decrease verbosity.
  -p PYTHON_EXE, --python=PYTHON_EXE
                        The Python interpreter to use, e.g.,
                        --python=python2.5 will use the python2.5 interpreter
                        to create the new environment.  The default is the
                        interpreter that virtualenv was installed with
                        (/usr/bin/python3.5)
```

You need to install Python 2.7.9 on your system first. And as said in another answer, you can have multiple Python versions installed on your system side by side.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple binaries of python on the same system. Install the version you need and use this command.

```
virtualenv -p {python binary location} {name of virtualenv}
```

The `virtualenvwrapper` commands `mkvirtualenv` and `mkproject` will both accept the `-p` argument and pass it to `virtualenv` when creating virtual environments.